# Understand XGboost learning

Tags: boosting

I'm an experienced SWE and trying to learn some ML.

I'm reading the [XGBoost tutorial](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model.html) and I'd like to further understand one point in the learning process.

It appears from the following picture that when spliting a leave, it first tries to sort the samples by their G(i) and H(i) scores and then do a linear scan to find the best split that maximize the gain. My question is:
1. Based on what does the algorithm sort (we have G(i) and H(i), not just one metric?)
2. Why does the split have to be continous? Shouldn't it be entirely possible that distinct chunk of the sorted sequence form one leave and the rest another leave?

Explanations are appreciated. I'm sure I'm missing something.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't sort by the score. It sorts by by the values of the data dimension being considered as a potential split and then calculates the score by moving g and h from right to left in the sum during the scan.

For example in the figure it appears the people are sorted by age.

As far as question two, it only adds one split at a time it's quite common for there to be multiple splits on one feature either in the same tree or another tree in the ensemble which allows the ensemble to approximate arbitrary functions or complex decision boundaries like you describe.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. That explains well! This is my first time posting questions on stackoverflow/crossvalidates. I'm surprised it gets answered so well in such a short period of time.